# Merging one polygon that is entirely contained in another polygon in R

Tags: r, polygon, merge

I am working with subcounty division polygons obtained with the `tigris` package in R. Some of the county subdivisions polygons are entirely contained within another polygon. For an example of this, we can look at the Twin Cities metro area in Minnesota:

```
library(tigris)
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

# Get county and county subdivisions
county_MN <- counties(state = "MN")
subcounty_MN <- county_subdivisions(state = "MN")

# Merge county names with the subcounty data
subcounty_MN <- county_MN%>% 
  select(GEOID, NAME) %>% 
  st_join(subcounty_MN , ., st_within) %>% 
  rename(GEOID = GEOID.x,
         NAME = NAME.x,
         county_GEOID = GEOID.y,
         county_name = NAME.y)

# Take a look at the metro area
subcounty_MN %>% 
  filter(county_name %in% c("Anoka", "Carver", "Dakota", "Hennepin", "Ramsey", "Scott", "Washington")) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf()
```

You can see examples where there are smaller polygons entirely within a larger polygon. I would like to "absorb" these smaller polygons into the larger polygon, so that the smaller polygon no longer exists but I do not want to leave a hole in the larger polygon.

I imagine the solution will use `st_join`, `st_union`, and/or `st_within`.

Comment: Do you want a procedure that identifies *and* then merges any of these instances?

Comment: Ah yes that's probably an important piece of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: The trick is to first remove all holes using sfheaders::st_remove_holes, and then use st_contains. How do you want to "merge" the contained polygons with the containers - ie what do you want to do with the attributes from the two (or more) contributing polygons?

Comment: I want to keep the attributes from the larger polygon, the "container" polygon as you put it.

Comment: Are there any cases where a hole is really a hole, and doesn't have a little feature filling it? And that you would want to keep as a hole in the output? Sorry for the continual clarification requests but I keep thinking of cases that will break my algorithm.

Comment: I appreciate your thoroughness. I don't actually know if any of the holes are really holes. My assumption is that there aren't any holes that are actually holes